# How to test Java Scheduler (ScheduledExecutorService)?

Tags: java, unit-testing

This is my code of trying java scheduler to test print a message after a year.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class testMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService sheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(6);
        // once in a Year
        long nextYear = TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(365);
        sheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("You successfully finished another year woohooo");
            }
        }, nextYear, TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(365), TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
}
```

I need to test this without waiting a year. can you help me to workout?

Comment: Yout think your app will run 365 days without dying. Possible but rather unlikely.

Comment: There is no way, you need to wait 365 days in front of your pc. :) Or just provisionally use `TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(10)` to check its behaviour then restore back it to years.

Comment: There is no need to test built-in methods. Assume that they work. If you want to test your codes logic, make the waiting-time configurable and use a small amount for testing (10 milliseconds for example). Otherwise, you can also mock it by wrapping this waiting logic into a dedicated method and when testing you give it a mocked method which just triggers directly.

Comment: One approach is to use dependency injection to inject the `ScheduledExecutorService` from the outside instead of creating it yourself. That way you can pass in a fake, see e.g. https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Using-Spies-(and-Fakes)#case-study-2-to-test-a-jobscheduler-that-uses-scheduledexecutorservice. Or, obviously, you can make the waiting time configurable and use a a few millis in the test.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to test built-in methods. Assume that they work. If you want to test the logic of the code, make the waiting-time configurable and use a small amount for testing (10 milliseconds for example). Otherwise, you can also mock it by wrapping this waiting logic into a dedicated method, and when testing you give it a mocked method which just triggers directly.

for example

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class testMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService sheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(6);
        // once in a Year
        long nextYear = TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(365);
        sheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("You successfully finished another year woohooo");
            }
        }, nextYear, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(2), TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
}
```